# What is the correct way to move an rss feed? Is there a temporary workaround for google reader users?

Tags: web-hosting, website, 301-redirect, google-analytics

I run a website that has published its RSS feed at a given location for years. However, I'm now forced to move the feed to another URL. Let's say the original URL was `www.example.com/rss.xml` and the new address is `feeds.example.com/example`.

I see from google webmaster tools that there's lots of activity picking up feeds from the existing URL.

I understand that HTTP-correct way of signalling a move to the feed fetcher is for the HTTP header on `www.example.com/rss.xml` to send a response code `301 "Moved Permanently"` and the target URL.

With existing constraints on the site, I can't do this right now. **Is there a way I can tell google reader about the redirection?** Say through google site tools or maybe some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, 301 is **THE** correct way. Is the server Apache and if so, Rewrite is disabled in .htaccess?

[Howto](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/redirecting-wordpress-feeds-to-feedburner.html) redirect feed urls to feedburner in .htaccess

If you have access to the code of the whatever-your-blog-engine-might be, you could use the language to modify the HTTP headers to return the "301 MOVED PERMANENTLY" instead of 200 FOUND". If so, which software/language are you running?

Comment: The .htaccess redirection worked fine thanks! (Using Apache under Linux)